# Import .csv into MongoDB creating arrays with objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, csv, object, import

I am starting to familiarize with MongoDB and now i have to import a relative large .csv file into a Mongo collection. So far I was able to import the .csv file without big problems (either with mongoimport or through Studio 3T). However, I would like to create some arrays for each specific document. Maybe by explaining with an example my data I could make it clearer.

```
worker_id | gender | birth | employer_id | start     | end       | type   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CAD1213   | M      | 1990  | WRF1119     | 15jun2018 | 31dec2018 | 11.1.1 |
CAD1213   | M      | 1990  | WAC1134     | 1jan2019  | 31dec2019 | 12.1.1 |
CAF1456   | F      | 1972  | WAC1134     | 15aug1988 | 17sep2016 | 55.0.1 |
CAR5567   | F      | 1991  | WER9280     | 15jun2018 | 31dec2018 | 1.1.1  |
CAR5578   | F      | 1989  | WHI1176     | 15jun2011 | 1nov2011  | 12.2.5 |
CAR5578   | F      | 1989  | WHI1176     | 2nov2011  | 31dec2012 | 12.2.5 |
```

This is just a mere example with few fields (columns). I have data for job contracts where: *worker_id* is the the identification of the worker, *gender* the sex, *birth* refers to the birth year of the worker, *employer_id* is the identification of each employer, *start* and *end* the beginning and the end of each specific work contract, respectively, while *type* is the specific work contract. The whole database obviously is characterize by more fields.

With the classic .csv import, for each line I would obtain a different document with specific *_id*s and each column would represent the fields. However, I would like to have as '_id' (although not necessarily) the value of the *worker_id*. As you can see, some *worker_id* are repeated in the column (in a file of over 17 millions of row you can imagine how many replica I could have), therefore it would be impossibile to select this field as *_id*.

Here it comes what I am struggling to obtain. I would like to create an array (for example called *contracts*) which contains information of each specific contract, hence objects, in this case the columns *employer_id*, *start*, *end*, and *type*. For some workers we would have just an element in the array (CAF1456 and CAR5567 in the example) while for others more than one (CAD1213 and CAR5578 in the example). Therefore, an hypothetical document would be like the following one:

```
_id: "CAD1213"
gender: "M"
birth: "1990"
contracts: Array
  0: Object
     employer_id: "WRF1119"
     start: "15jun2018"
     end: "31dec2018"
     type: "11.1.1"
  1: Object  
     employer_id: "WAC1134"
     start: "1jan1988"
     end: "31dec2019"
     type: "12.1.1"

_id: "CAF1456"
gender: "F"
birth: "1972"
contracts: Array
  0: Object
     employer_id: "WAC1134"
     start: "15aug1988"
     end: "17sep2016"
     type: "55.0.1"

_id: "CAR5567"
gender: "F"
birth: "1991"
contracts: Array
  0: Object
     employer_id: "WER9280"
     start: "15jun2018"
     end: "31dec2018"
     type: "1.1.1"

_id: "CAR5578"
gender: "F"
birth: "1989"
contracts: Array
  0: Object
     employer_id: "WHI1176"
     start: "15jun2011"
     end: "1nov2011"
     type: "12.2.5"
  1: Object  
     employer_id: "WHI1176"
     start: "2nov2011"
     end: "31dec2012"
     type: "12.2.5"
```

As far as I know this procedure cannot be performed directly with mongoimport, then it has to be performed after importing the whole .csv document (I guess). I hope someone could provide me some hints, suggestions or links where I can find some help in achieving this structure. Moreover, if other structures of the documents could be more suitable for my example, I am eager to know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just some thoughts. The final data model should drive the process of the whole import of the CSV file or files. The _mongoimport_ has options to import only a subset of the fields; and you can import data into multiple collections (categorized by the data). Then, based on data model, merge the data together, refine it, etc., using queries and aggregation framework or even an application.

Comment: I was able (one way or another to solve the issue). By using Python I have imported the .csv databse and from it I have generate a .json-type document with nested arrays. Therefore, with pymongo I have imported the documents into my MongoDB database. You can fine the code here: https://github.com/nicolacaravaggio/CICO/blob/master/from_csv_to_json.ipynb